# ColdFusion 2016 file not found error

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I installed ColdFusion 2016 developer edition on windows 8.1. I copied my CF project folder MyCFProject to `C:\ColdFusion2016\cfusion\wwwroot\CFIDE` directory and opened `http://localhost/MyCFProject/index.cfm` where index.cfm is in MyCFProject folder. This url worked fine and I can run the app successfully. But I copied another project folder `MySecondProject` that also has an index.cfm file and opened url `http://localhost/MySecondProject/index.cfm` that gives me the following error. Both projects were copied from Windows 7 that has ColdFusion 11 installed and both projects work fine there:

**Error**:

```
File not found: /MySecondProject/Index.cfm
Browser     Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36
Remote Address      ::1
Referrer    
Date/Time   23-Jul-16 08:00 PM
Stack Trace


coldfusion.runtime.TemplateNotFoundException: File not found: /MySecondProject/Index.cfm
    at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:145)
    at coldfusion.filter.LicenseFilter.invoke(LicenseFilter.java:30)
    at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:94)
    at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:60)
    at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
    at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62)
    at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:219)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
```

Comment: Are you sure your webroot is `C:\ColdFusion2016\cfusion\wwwroot\CFIDE`? I'd expect `C:\ColdFusion2016\cfusion\wwwroot` instead.

Comment: @Alex Thank you for trying to help. Yes, the webroot is `C:\ColdFusion2016\cfusion\wwwroot\CFIDE` for both the projects and both the project directories MyCFProject and MySecondProject are copied the this webroot. First one works, the second one does not. Moreover, both projects work on Windows 7 where webroot is `C:\ColdFusion11\cfusion\wwwroot\CFIDE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error and it works now. In ColdFusion 11, when I copied the project directory to the path `C:\ColdFusion11\cfusion\wwwroot\CFIDE`, it automatically appeared in IIS7.5 (maybe the CF installation sets up this path to IIS). However, in ColdFusion 2016, it seems you have to create a virtual directory yourself and point it to the physical path of your app (in my case, the path described above). Another possibility is that during the ColdFusion 2016 installation, there was an option to point `C:\ColdFusion2016\cfusion\wwwroot\CFIDE` to IIS8, but I either ignored it or opted out of that installation option.

**OBSERVATION**: Moreover, I noticed that in CF 11, when you copy your project directory to `C:\ColdFusion11\cfusion\wwwroot\CFIDE` it gets connected to IIS and when you browse the site from IIS you get the home page URL as `http:/localhost/CFIDE/MyProject`; whereas in ColdFusion 2016, when you copy your project folder to `C:\ColdFusion2016\cfusion\wwwroot\CFIDE` you still have to manually create a virtual directory in IIS and point it to `C:\ColdFusion2016\cfusion\wwwroot\CFIDE` and that the URL of your site is `http://localhost/MyProject` [without CFIDE folder in the URL]. It may have something to do with the installation options I may have chosen when I installed CF 2016.